# Does Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality holds for semi-inner-product space

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Does Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality holds for semi-inner-product space, defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-inner-product#Semi-inner-products_for_Banach_spaces ?

I have found out in this case, $ <x,y><y,x>  \leq  <x,x><y,y>$

I have check other posts on MSE but all of them are based on different definition of semi inner product space.

Math newbie thanks you.

Comment: Isn't property (5) in the definition on that Wikipedia page exactly the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Thanks for point that out. I thought [5] is a definition? Or could we prove this property [5] from the properties [1]-[4]?

Comment: It's part of the definition.